# Make R print just the result

Tags: r

Having a very simple R file ( mine.r ):

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
sq<-function(n){return(n*n)}
sq(as.numeric(args[1]))
```

I run it using `Rscript mine.r 2` and I get the following input: `[1] 4\n`.

How should I run it to get just `4` (without `[1]` and `\n`?

I tried to use `--silent` flag (`Rscript --silent mine.r 2`) it didn't help.

**Remark**: In my real problem I run some complicated calculations using R. I invoke the R code from my ruby code using

> a = `Rscript sample.size.mean.r`

and want `a` to have value `"4"` (without cutting off the head and the tail of the output using ruby code).

Comment: `cat` returns NULL, so would seem to be most unwise to use it when calling R from another running program. The `[1]` and `\n` are side-effects of the REPL in the R console. It's unclear what you are attempting. Are you trying to get a quoted `4` returned to a running instance of ruby/ Or are you trying to get a "4" output to a file? Or something else? And where did this variable named `a` come from?

Comment: @BondedDust huh, what does the return *value* of `cat` matter? if you're uncertain about the computation, then just do it first and perform whatever checks, and output the result to the output stream using `cat` instead of the default `print`.

Comment: I thought I explained why it might matter. It's certainly possible that you understand the questioner's intent better than I. I thought that using Rscript with `--silent` suggested a goal that was different than seeing what would be observed at an open R console.

Comment: @BondedDust I don't think you did explain why returning `NULL` matters. All I see is that "it would seem to be most unwise", but no reasoning to explain why. As for OP's intent I think it's pretty clear - they just want to use `R` to do some computation and then use the answer they get elsewhere and are trying to use the standard output for the communication.

Comment: `cat` or `write` would be fine for output to a file. If inter-process communication between R and ruby were desired, then `cat` might be problematic.

Comment: @BondedDust uhh, :eyeroll:, I give up, you keep saying the same thing over and over without explaining **why** it might be problematic or unwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
sq <- function(n){return(n*n)}
result <- sq(as.numeric(args[1]))

cat(result)
```